# My solution to finding probability of winning a game is 21/512, whereas the answer given is 21/1205. What is logical error in my solution.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification, conditional-probability, problem-solving

Consider following question:

> A bag containing $3$ blue, $2$ red, $2$ green, and $1$ black ball to be used for a game. The rules of the game are simple. A player is required to randomly choose a ball from the bag and put it back after noticing its color. If the first ball to be chosen is blue, the player gets three more turns. The player retrieving a black ball in any of subsequent turns ($2$-$4$) is declared the winner. What is the probability of a player winning on third attempt?"

I solved the above question as following:

"Winning on $3$rd attempt means that the $1$st ball is blue and second ball is not black and $3$rd ball is black. Let A = $1$st ball is blue, Let B = $2$nd ball is not black Let C = $3$rd ball is black Therefore, Winning on 3rd attempt means (A and B and C). Since, A, B and C are independent events, therefore P(win on third turn) = $ \displaystyle P(A) \cdot P(B) \cdot P(C) = \frac 38 \cdot \frac 78 \cdot \frac 18 = \frac{21}{512}$

However, the answer to this question is mentioned as $ \frac {21}{1205}$ (without giving complete solution).

My question is that how the answer is $ \frac {21}{1205}$ and if this is the correct answer then what is incorrect in my solution.

Comment: Please write an *INFORMATIVE* title... one that relates to the specific problem, branch of math, etc., in the problem.

Comment: David, my question is asking what is incorrect in my solution. I have mentioned the branch of mathematics.

Comment: It is unclear to me what constitutes "an attempt."  Is "an attempt" in reference to the entire game of up to four pulls?  Is "an attempt" in reference only to the pulls after a blue ball was drawn (if it was even drawn in the first place)?  If so, does the "attempt" numbering scheme begin with "attempt 1" being the first pull after the initial blue making "attempt 1" actually the second ball drawn, or was that actually "attempt 2"?

Comment: "*Please write an INFORMATIVE title*"  "*My question is asking what is incorrect... I have mentioned the branch of mathematics*"  The purpose of a good title is so that people scrolling past the thousands of posts and see only the title of the questions can tell whether or not the post is relevant to their interests, something they can answer, or something they have similar questions about and would benefit from clicking on your post.  *Thousands* of posts are people asking "what is wrong with what I did" and a title like you have now does nothing to help in that matter.

Comment: JMoravitz : attempt here means that player is taking out a ball from urn; obviously, if the first ball is not blue, then the game ends and there are no remaining attempts of taking out ball from the urn

Comment: @saqib:  But none of that is in your TITLE!  What if you saw a title like:  "I need help on my math problem".  Well... it shows you need HELP.  That it involves MATH.  But it doesn't help because it is vague.  JMoravitz explained perfectly what is wrong with your title.  Look at other titles on this site.

Comment: If that is your interpretation of the problem and the problem is written correctly, then I agree with your answer.  Some things stand out as odd however... Why $1205=5\times 241$?  A prime factor of $241$?  That is too bizarre of a number to have appeared in a denominator in a normal question like this.  Why the [conditional-probability] tag?  Are you sure the question was not phrased every-so-slightly differently?  For instance... "**Given that the player wins** *what is the probability he won on the third attempt?*"

Comment: @saqib:  I noticed you just revised your problem but failed to fix your title.  It is clear you're not profiting from the help offered you (by me, JMoravitz, ...), so I'll leave to help others who incorporate guidance from experts.

Comment: @JMoravitz First ball drawn is counted is first attempt. If the ball drawn on first attempt is blue then payer get three more attempts to draw the ball. The player wins when black ball is drawn in any of the additional three attempts and game stops. If the player does not draw black ball in any of the additional three attempts then game stops and player looses the game.

Comment: The way I read this question initially, **after** you draw and replace a blue ball you have **three attempts** to draw a black ball, and the question is what is the probability that you will actually use all of those three attempts. That is, you have already drawn a blue ball; then you try once to draw the black ball but you fail, you try again and fail again, and you try a third time and win. On the other hand: (1) the problem really is ambiguous and your reading is plausible; (2) the probability under my interpretation is $147/4096,$ so the mysterious answer must occur some other way.

Comment: Given that the numerators agree and the denominator is a weird combo of adding a leading zero and permitting the digits, my guess is: extremely weird typo

Comment: @DavidK the question asks that what is the probability of taking out black ball on third attempt (i.e., first one is blue ball, second one is any ball other than black, and third ball is black ball). The game is supposed to be played in a following way: If the first ball is not blue, then game ends and player looses. If the first ball is blue, then player replaces the ball and it gets three chances to take out a black ball in order to win the game. So, if on any of the next three draw player takes out black ball then it wins the game. Otherwise, after exhausting all three attempts it looses.

Comment: @DavidK Note that game stops when player draws black ball after taking out first blue ball. Further, the ball is replaced after every draw.

Comment: Yeah, yeah, we read the rules in the problem statement. You don't have to keep repeating them. No amount of repetition of what is already written will make the words "third attempt" any less ambiguous.